# How to define grandparent for adjacency relationships

Tags: sqlalchemy

```
class Node(Base):
    ...
    id = Column(Numeric, primary_key=True)

    parent_id = Column(Numeric, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))
    parent = relation("Node", lazy="joined", remote_side=id)

    grandparent = ?
```

I can not use hybrid_property because it doesn't define a target mapper class.

How can I set grandparent relation with column_property, relation, association_proxy, or other way?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: Why not use `node.parent.parent` with `joinedload`?

Comment: Is it possible to use this way inside class with declarative base?

Answer (score 0):

It's works on SQLAlchemy==0.7.9

```
class Node(Base):
    ...
    grandparent_id  = association_proxy('parent','parent_id')
    grandparent = association_proxy('parent','parent')
```